# Upcasting external java libraries in scala using "with" keyword produces type mismatch error

Tags: java, scala

I am utilizing an external Java library with a class that implements several interfaces, but I am confounded about the details of how to properly instantiate the class so that later functions see a particular interface it implements.

I have tried upcasting directly with something like:

```
val my_obj : InterfaceName = new ClassThatImplementsInterface()
```

while this seems to work in a basic example it was not accepted by the compiler in my particular application context. So, I tried to use the following syntax, which was also accepted by a compiler when I created some separate simple demonstration code:

```
import Demo._

object MyClass {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {    
    val my_obj : Demo with MyInterface = new Demo with MyInterface  
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this syntax also fails to compile in the particular application context. So, for example using a jar file called javaplex.jar, the following:

```
import edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.interfaces.AbstractSearchableMetricSpace
import edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.impl.ExplicitMetricSpace

object MetricSpaceBuilder {
  def buildSpace(similarity_matrix : Array[Array[Double]]): Unit = {    
    val metric_space : ExplicitMetricSpace with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]] = new ExplicitMetricSpace(similarity_matrix) with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]]
  }
}
```

compiled with:

```
scalac -cp javaplex.jar  MetricSpaceBuilder.scala
```

produces the following error message:

```
MetricSpaceBuilder.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.impl.ExplicitMetricSpace with edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.interfaces.AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]]
 required: edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.impl.ExplicitMetricSpace with edu.stanford.math.plex4.metric.interfaces.AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]]
    val metric_space : ExplicitMetricSpace with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]] = new ExplicitMetricSpace(similarity_matrix) with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Array[Int]]
                                                                                            ^
one error found
```

Why does the compiler report that it has not found the required type?

Answer (score 2):

It compiles if I write

```
object MetricSpaceBuilder {
  def buildSpace(similarity_matrix : Array[Array[Double]]): Unit = {    
    val metric_space : ExplicitMetricSpace with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Integer] = new ExplicitMetricSpace(similarity_matrix) with AbstractSearchableMetricSpace[Integer]
  }
}
```

Since `ExplicitMetricSpace` already implements `AbstractSearchableMetricSpace<Integer>` it cannot implement `AbstractSearchabelMetricSpace<int[]>` too.

Comment: Great, this works, thanks. I guess I should be aware that this type mismatch message may actually be trying to communicate that there is a incompatibility between implemented interfaces in the external library.